# Cannot be resolved or it is not a field?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-library

I'm developing an Android Application, and my libraries are  updated and layout is perfectly designed.

```
View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.***apklist_item***, null);
(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.***appname***);
```

at **apklist_item** and **appname** these lines I'mm getting an error, how to rectify this ? 
Kindly suggest me for developing Android APP.
[image]
Thanks.

Comment: What error you are getting?? Post your LogCt and Source code. Then only people can help you.

Comment: Your R file is not getting generated.Is there any problem with your resource file? May a perfect clean & build will help you

Comment: Cleaned and Build Perfectly , still same error ..

Comment: can you share console data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is due to some reasons.
1. Due to not generating **R** file in gen folder.
2. Check is there any error in xml files.
3. Check import It seems you import android.R instead of packagename.R

Check above three conditions It may be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, your inflated layout `apklist_item.xml` doesn't contain a view named `appname`